# Enviar correo con PHPMailer consultando emails a mysql

Tags: phpmailer

Lo primero gracias por todos los aportes, me han sido de gran ayuda.

He consultado varios hilos y no he visto nada (perdón si lo duplico)

Tengo una duda a la hora de enviar email a mis clientes, tengo un base de datos con pedidos registrados de clientes, y lo que quiero hacer es enviar a los clientes un correo cuando el pedido este pasado de fecha automáticamente (con una tarea programada en el servidor).

EL problema es que cuando ejecuto el fichero php me manda todos los pedidos a todos los clientes en vez de mandar el pedido que corresponde a cada cliente. Adjunto el código a ver si me podéis echar una mano. Gracias!!

```
    <?php
$fecha          = "DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y/%m/%d')";
$fechamenos3    = "DATE_SUB($fecha,INTERVAL 3 DAY)";
$fechamas3      = "DATE_ADD($fecha,INTERVAL 1 DAY)";


$result=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM produccion JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id = produccion.id_cliente WHERE fecha_salida >= $fechamenos3 AND fecha_salida <= $fecha");

    require("../enviomail/class.phpmailer.php");
        
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->From     = "correo";
        $mail->FromName = "nombre"; 
        $mail->IsSMTP(); 
        $mail->Host = "**";
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
        $mail->Username = "**";
        $mail->Password = "**";                      
                                 
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))   
    {
        $producto   = $row["producto"];
        $correo     = $row["email"];
        $mail->AddAddress($correo);
        $mail->WordWrap = 50; 
        $mail->IsHTML(true);     
        $mail->Subject  =  "Asunto";
        $mail->Body     =  "Su pedido <b>$producto</b> esta fuera de plazo. \n<br />". ;   
                           
                           
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error:" . $mail->ErrorInfo . "<br />";
            break; 
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sin saber qué datos hay en cada lugar y cómo los obtienes, es BIEN difícil decirte nada :) No sabemos qué hay en `$result` ni cómo lo asociaste a `$correo`. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: ya edite el código,